# Compute the maximum of two values in Transact-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to select objects based on a parameter if this one is bigger than a defined date:

```
select o.* from objects as o 
where o.modifieddate >= max(<Search Term>,20190401)
```

I got the error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server [-2147527900]
The max function requires 1 argument(s)
```

What's the right syntax for this ?

This is an Enterprise Architect Sparx select (which must be a SQL Server select). 
The "<Search Term>" is the keyword to get the value typed by the user in the query window. And it is a string.

Comment: You would use your parameter not some random string literal. And why is your search term a string and not a date? Also, for string representation of dates you should use the ANSI compliant YYYYMMDD. Anything else can get wrong dates based on local settings.

Comment: Do you get an error when you run it?   Try posting your actual code instead of psuedocode.  You may be obfuscating the actual syntax error.

Comment: Or are you trying to determine which date is more recent? If that is the case then use a CASE expression.

Comment: Or simply do `where o.modifieddate >= date1 AND o.modifieddate >= date2`?

Comment: @DavidG This is the best, simplest, and most direct answer. It forces the OP to think about the problem properly  Please consider posting it as an answer to the question. You'll have my upvote

Answer (score 4):

You might use a CASE statement:

```
declare @InputDate datetime;
declare @CriteriumDate datetime;

set @InputDate = convert(datetime, '<Search Term>',103);
set @CriteriumDate =  = convert(datetime, '1/04/2019',103);

select o.* from objects as o 
where o.modifieddate >= case when @InputDate < @CriteriumDate then @CriteriumDate else @InputDate end;
```

(I introduced some date variables to make the query more readable.)

Edit:

As @lvr123 pointed out, using CASE statements becomes ugly when multiple values should be checked. If the version of SQL Server allows it, the following query might be used in that case:

```
declare @InputDate datetime;
declare @Criteria table (dt datetime);

insert into @Criteria (dt) values (convert(datetime, '<Search Term 1>',103));
insert into @Criteria (dt) values (convert(datetime, '<Search Term 2>',103));
insert into @Criteria (dt) values (convert(datetime, '1/04/2019',103));

select o.* from objects as o 
where o.modifieddate >= (select max(dt) from @Criteria);
```

This code can be somewhat optimized, of course. And this example is hard coded with three values. Adding more values only requires adding additional INSERT-queries on the @Criteria table.

Comment: The CASE statement is a nice solution but that's becoming limited when dealing with more than 2 values: `select max(value1,value2,value3);` will become tricky with a CASE statement

Comment: @lvr123 That's very true. Nested CASE statements would become very ugly. I will update my answer with an extra example in case multiple dates should be checked...

Comment: Maybe wrap @BartHofland's script into a stored procedure, then pass in a [table valued parameter](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/using-sql-servers-table-valued-parameters/). I like the scalability of this. +1

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to play around with populating the `VALUES` list, but something like this might work for you, too:

```
SELECT
  o.*
FROM
  objects AS o
WHERE
  o.modifieddate >=
    (
      SELECT
        MAX(v.Criteria)
      FROM
        (
          VALUES
            (<SearchTerm_1>)
            ...
           ,(<SearchTerm_N>)
           ,(20190401) --<-- Your Default Value
        ) AS v (Criteria)
    );
```